# Are questions involving the technical details of the operation of a device on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I understand that questions involving the usage of a particular electronic device are off topic. However, I asked [a question about refrigeration compressors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115886/why-do-refrigeration-compressors-stall-when-switched-off-and-on-quickly) and a user has commented that it may be off topic. The question is not really about the usage of the equipment itself but the technical details of the operation of the device and how and why certain conditions may cause the device to operate incorrectly.

Are such questions on topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the question is fine here. It has a lot to do with the properties of motors, which are definitely part of electrical engineering.